# How to write multiple rows in CSV from enumerated array in Python

Tags: python, csv, scripting

I'm trying to create a CSV which creates new rows underneath one header, for a scaling amount of data (rows). Currently it just puts everything in one row side by side (see screenshot below). I'm not sure how the interaction works between the data all being stored in a for loop and array and the csv.writer.writerow(s) works. A lot of examples I've looked up are all with predefined names for the rows etc. not a enumerated array. This is what the code currently looks like:

## Utility function to create 2-dimensional array

```
def create_array(m, n):
    dims = System.Array.CreateInstance(System.Int32, 2)
    dims[0] = m
    dims[1] = n
    return System.Array.CreateInstance(System.Object, dims)

# List of all primary get_ fxns
patient = get_current('Patient')
case = get_current('Case')
plan = get_current('Plan')

# Collect data
planDose = plan.TreatmentCourse.TotalDose
structureSet = plan.GetStructureSet()
roiNames = [r.OfRoi.Name for r in structureSet.RoiGeometries if r.PrimaryShape != None]
numROIs = len(roiNames) 

# Create an array that holds header information
header_row = create_array(1,8)
header_row[0,0] = 'ROI'
header_row[0,1] = 'Volume [cc]'
header_row[0,2] = 'D99 [cGy]'
header_row[0,3] = 'D98 [cGy]'
header_row[0,4] = 'D95 [cGy]'
header_row[0,5] = 'Average [cGy]'
header_row[0,6] = 'D2 [cGy]'
header_row[0,7] = 'D1 [cGy]'    

# Create a 2-dimensional array for values per ROI
data_array = create_array(len(roiNames),8)

for idx, roi in enumerate(roiNames):
    # Edit this if other dose statistics are desired
    volume = planDose.GetDoseGridRoi(RoiName=roi).RoiVolumeDistribution.TotalVolume
    d99, d98, d95, d2, d1 = planDose.GetDoseAtRelativeVolumes(RoiName=roi, RelativeVolumes=[.99,0.98,0.95,.02,.01])
    average = planDose.GetDoseStatistic(RoiName=roi, DoseType='Average')
    # Load the array
    data_array[idx,0] = roi
    data_array[idx,1] = volume
    data_array[idx,2] = d99
    data_array[idx,3] = d98
    data_array[idx,4] = d95
    data_array[idx,5] = average
    data_array[idx,6] = d2
    data_array[idx,7] = d1

#Scrape patient info to text file for import to Excel 
ptName = patient.Name
mrn = patient.PatientID
    
#header = ['Patient Name', 'MRN']
#data = [ptName, mrn]
fileName = "SBRT Eval " + str(ptName) + "_" + str(mrn) + ".csv"
with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header_row)
    writer.writerow(data_array)
```

and it exports the following (note how each structure name (ie Lung_L) is followed by the data but then repeats: [Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KYiZ.png)

For clarity, I'm working in RayStation trying to script some processes but I just can't figure out how to make the CSV export to new lines, neatly, rather than in one row.

Do I need a for loop to iterate through the data_array set?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding I've tweaked your array to

```
def create_array(m, n):
  return [[0 for x in range(n)] for y in range(m)]
```

which leads to the definition being

```
header_row[0][0] = 'ROI'
header_row[0][1] = 'Volume [cc]'
header_row[0][2] = 'D99 [cGy]'
etc...
```

With this array setup you can use writerow**s** to iterate trough the array. You also need to add "newline=''" to avoid blank lines in output.

```
with open(fileName, 'w', newline='') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(header_row)
  writer.writerows(data_array)
```